# Python WSGI Server for Kubernetes?

Tags: django, kubernetes

I want to run my Django application in Kubernetes.

In Kubernetes the available ressources could limited, and the amount of CPUs you get with traditional methods could be wrong.

For Go this gets handled with https://github.com/uber-go/automaxprocs

Up to now I use gunicorn, but I could switch to a different wsgi server.

Which wsgi server is recommended to run Django applications in Kubernetes?

Comment: Is your Django application actually CPU-bound?  How does it behave incorrectly if the physical number or cores disagrees with the CPU limits (something that's very possible without container infrastructure)?

Comment: My application does not run in Kubernetes yet. I prepare for that. The application is not CPU bound.